# Bootstrap 4 Modal appearing backdrop angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4 in angular2 project,in multiple component in one component However, my modal is appearing underneath the grey fade (backdrop) and is non editable.[image]

firstComponent.html

```
<batopPage>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="lgModal.show()">Large modal</button>
    <!-- Large modal -->
    <div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn" (click)="lgModal.hide()">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</batopPage>
```

firstComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'firstcomponent',
  template: require('./firstComponent.html')
})
export class Modals {
  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal: ModalDirective;

  showChildModal(): void {
    this.childModal.show();
  }

  hideChildModal(): void {
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
}
```

otherComponent.html

```
<firstcomponent></firstcomponent>
```

Comment: Not sure anyone will be able to help here without a minimal plunker showing your exact code...

Comment: I don't know anything about angular2 but you can always refer http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ here. it will make it much more easy for you to manager bootstrap with the given link. No need to manage it by your own.

Answer (score 3):

To make your modal editable:

option 1:
add to your modal's html tag:

```
[config]="{backdrop: false}"
```

option 2: 
go to your main (s)css file and add:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

adjust your component's z-index accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is an old issue but I had a similar  Issue on Angular 5, bootstrap 4 and this issue ranked rather high on my google searches.

I started having this issue when I added an animation to a component that contains a modal.

The piece of offending code in my project was:

```
export const menuAnimation =    trigger('MenuSlideInOut', [
  state('in', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(210px, 0, 0)'
  })),
  state('out', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0%, 0, 0)'
  })),
  transition('in => out', animate('400ms 0.1s ease-in-out')),
  transition('out => in', animate('400ms 0.1s ease-in-out'))
])
```

It seems like any movement of the component containing the modal will break the modal.

Manually adjusting the z-index did not solve the issue. This issue only occurs when you use the standard  js libraries that ships with bootstrap. Using a  angular port of those libraries solves the issue. I used [ngx-bootsrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) , but [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) might also work

Answer (score -1):

please do inspect element check out classes applied to modal and main body in your page,i'm pretty sure this is because modal-backdrop active and stucked.
here are few things you can do

1) just add data-dismiss="modal" to button

2)If modal hide or visible, faded background is remained and does not let you click any where you can forcefully remove those by using below piece of code.

first hide your modal div element.

```
$('modalId').modal('hide');
```

secondly remove 'modal-open' class from body and '.modal-backdrop' at the end of the page.

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```